# JNI Headers not found from xcode

Tags: java, xcode, java-native-interface, jnienv

After installing Java  7, All of sudden xcode failed to compile my project saying jni.h file not found error. I've tried by removing java 7 manually with 'rm' command. If I provide compiler flags in xcode project build setting with the path : "-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers/" , it compiles fine. 
My system is Mac OSX 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while installing soprano from Macports. I think you have to install the command-line tool from Xcode. Use the terminal and "xcode-select --install" (w/o quotation marks). This worked fine for me. I hope this is helpful for you, too.